# Mapnik Input of Mercator Flat File

Tags: python, coordinate-system, mapnik

I'm just starting with Mapnik.  I followed an example found online to dump an input datasource into a small output image.  So far, so good.

Now I want to read a 16384x12800 PNG file I have.  It's a mercator projection of a fictional planet.  I created a `.wld` sidecar file:

```
0.021972656
0.0
0.0
-0.013290624
-179.9890116
85.0533511
```

The resulting `.envelope()` of the `mapnik.Gdal(...)` object is:

`Box2d(-179.999997928,-85.059990788,179.999997976,85.059996412)`

I'm using a layer SRS of `+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`.

With all this, the output file is blank (background color).

*What should the layer's SRS be for this kind of conversion?  Or is it something else I'm doing wrong?*

Here's the Python code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import mapnik

m = mapnik.Map(600,300)
m.background = mapnik.Color('steelblue')

s = mapnik.Style()
r = mapnik.Rule()
polygon_symbolizer = mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer()
polygon_symbolizer.fill = mapnik.Color('#f2eff9')
r.symbols.append(polygon_symbolizer)

line_symbolizer = mapnik.LineSymbolizer()
line_symbolizer.stroke = mapnik.Color('rgb(50%,50%,50%)')
line_symbolizer.stroke_width = 0.1
r.symbols.append(line_symbolizer)
s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('My Style',s)

ds = mapnik.Gdal(base='./maptest', file='world.png')
print(ds.envelope())

layer = mapnik.Layer('world')
layer.datasource = ds
layer.srs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
layer.styles.append('My Style')
print(layer.srs)

m.layers.append(layer)
m.zoom_all()

mapnik.render_to_file(m, 'small.png', 'png')
```

(The eventual intent is to break this big map up into tiles suitable for viewing on a slippy-map.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was "something else".

When changing from a polygon input to a raster file, it's necessary to create a `RasterSymbolizer` and append it to the rule symbols before adding that to the style rules.

```
...
line_symbolizer = mapnik.LineSymbolizer()
line_symbolizer.stroke = mapnik.Color('rgb(50%,50%,50%)')
line_symbolizer.stroke_width = 0.1
r.symbols.append(line_symbolizer)

raster_symbolizer = mapnik.RasterSymbolizer()
r.symbols.append(raster_symbolizer)

s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('My Style',s)
...
```

As for the answer to the actual question...  A `layer.srs` of

`+proj=merc`

was sufficient but this also worked:

`+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over`